# Add the value of value_counts on each point of a scatter plot

Tags: python, count, scatter-plot

I'm looking for adding the value of pollution['Energie'].value_counts() to each corresponding point on a scatterplot, but it doesn't work, can you help me please?
the dataset is about pollution emission of vehicules, with Nox emission on y-axis and Global Power Warming on x-axis and i'd like to add the nomber of each class of energie on the plot.
Thx for the help.

[image: pollution plot]

I already try to enumerate trough 'energie_counts', but It displays the value below the plot and this drastically reduces the size of the plot.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the answer, I found it:

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3xux.png)

I forgot to add `ax = plt.gca()` before the for loop and I added the ".values[0]" in the for loop to select only one value.

Comment: Hi Raios, welcome to SO. Please do not add code as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, add the code text in a codeblock. Thanks